# ElasticSearch - Add data node to the existing cluster. What is the best practice?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch cluster running, it contains 3 master nodes and 5 data nodes. The version is **7.6.0**.

The **master nodes** configuration looks like this:

```
cluster.name: es-cluster
node.name: master-0[1-3]
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
node.master: true
node.voting_only: false
node.data: false
node.ingest: false
node.ml: false
path.data: /data/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
http.port: 9200
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts:
   - IP-master-01:9300
   - IP-master-02:9300
   - IP-master-03:9300
   - IP-data-01:9300
   - IP-data-02:9300
   - IP-data-03:9300
   - IP-data-04:9300
   - IP-data-05:9300
```

The **data nodes** configuration:

```
cluster.name: es-cluster
node.name: data-0[1-5]
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
node.data: true
node.master: false
node.voting_only: false
node.ingest: false
node.ml: false
cluster.remote.connect: false
path.data: /data/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
http.port: 9200
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts:
   - IP-master-01:9300
   - IP-master-02:9300
   - IP-master-03:9300
   - IP-data-01:9300
   - IP-data-02:9300
   - IP-data-03:9300
   - IP-data-04:9300
   - IP-data-05:9300
```

I am going to add a new data node. Please, help me to understand the **best practice** of adding a node to the existing ES cluster.

The question is about the parameter **discovery.seed_hosts**. As far as I understand, it should be the same for all the ES nodes, so in my case, it means, that I should add this:

```
   - IP-data-06:9300
```

to the **discovery.seed_hosts** of all the ES nodes (of course, including the newly created node).

But does it mean, that I must restart all the other nodes after I add the 6-th data node? Otherwise, how the same configuration will be applied to all the ES nodes? Or maybe the same discovery.seed_hosts for all nodes is not important at all?

Thanks in advance for clarifying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a small mistake, the `discovery.seed_hosts` should have **only** the [master-eligible](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-settings.html) nodes, not all the nodes.

Since you are adding a data node, you don't need to add this node to this config, also you can remove all the nodes that are not master-eligible from this config in your new data node.

Just use this config in all your data nodes.

```
cluster.name: es-cluster
node.name: data-X
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
node.data: true
node.master: false
node.voting_only: false
node.ingest: false
node.ml: false
cluster.remote.connect: false
path.data: /data/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
http.port: 9200
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts:
   - IP-master-01:9300
   - IP-master-02:9300
   - IP-master-03:9300
```

There is no need to restart all your nodes now, but when you plan to do it, fix your config and leave only the master-eligible nodes in the `discovery.seed_hosts` setting.